# slide box in modal on ionic

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic-framework, slide

```js
example.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('learn-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'fade-in-scale'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.myActiveSlide = 0;

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  $scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };

});
```

```css
/* Modal */
.ion-nifty-modal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    top: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ;
}

.modal-backdrop.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
 <script id="learn-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-modal-view class="ion-nifty-modal">
      <div>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-slide-box>
          <ion-slide>
            <img src ="img/Episode/learn_more/ingredient/Text_ingredient.png" style = "width:50%; height:50%;">
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <img src ="img/Episode/learn_more/location/Text_location.png" style = "width:50%; height:50%;">
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
      </ion-content>
      </div>
    </ion-modal-view>
  </script>
```

Hi,

I tried to make a slide box in modal on ionic.

But it doesn't work properly.

The modal window appears. But there is no images

and it is not applied animation effect.

That is my code.

How can I fix it?

Please help me guys.

Thank you.

Comment: can you make a plnkr or codepen ?

Comment: Are you sure of image src urls? I tried your code and it's working properly. You can check in your browser if those urls are really correct using "ionic serve", then change the url (for example) to http://<your host>:8100/img/Episode/learn_more/ingredient/Text_ingredient.png

Comment: @macrog I tried to make a codepen. But it's not working....I really want to show you my screen on browser.

Comment: @beaver Urls are really correct. And I changed the url to the address that you gave me. But it's still not working...How can I do for that?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "change the url in your browser" after having launched "ionic serve" in your node.js console... I don't mean to change urls in your code. If you can see the pictures in the browser then their urls are correct.

Comment: @beaver No worry about that. Thank you. I changed some code. So, I finally make the animation. However, I wrote some text in slide,then the text is shown vertically. I cannot understand why characters are not shown generally.